# Incorrect Math in Principles of Modern Chemistry

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm reviewing some Chemistry and went to the appendix to see the Math required to finish the textbook completely. I'm 99% sure this is wrong, as I used an online equation solver and got a similar answer to mine substituting change in $x/y$ for other variables.

[image: image 1]

My result

[image]

Comment: I agree with you, looks like a typo in the book.

Comment: I would have preferred "a factor $a$ is missing" rather than this poor draft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the book is missing a factor of $a$ in the $(\Delta x)^2$ term

Comment: The next thing to do is see if there is an on-line set of errata for that book.  See if your error is listed there.  If not, the authors may appreciate being informed of it.